# VBA excel #VALUE error

Tags: excel, vba

I have a function that takes two string and it should add them.

```
Function teiseLopp(tekst1 As String, tekst2 As String) As String
    Dim stringidKoos As String
    stringidKoos = tekst1 & "" & tekst2
    teiseLopp = stringidKoos
End Function
```

And it should return the two strings together but it shows me #VALUE! = Value used in the formula is of the wrong data type. (Everything seems to be right datatype)

Comment: What are the values of `tekst1` and `tekst2` (and `stringidKoos`) when you step through your code?

Comment: They differentiate. I take values from excel cells. For example one cell is xyz and the other sus.

Comment: Have you defined you function `As String`. I.e. is your first line of code `Function teiseLopp(tekst1 As String, tekst2 As String) As String`?

Comment: Yes. It's just missing here from copying mistake I guess.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code should work if there aren't any errors in the cells you refer from. Maybe you have selected more than a single cell as input? You could give the following modification a try to see if that works. It handles you input as a `Range` and only operate on the value in the upper-left cell in each input range.

```
Function teiseLopp(tekst1 As Range, tekst2 As Range) As String
    Dim stringidKoos As String
    stringidKoos = tekst1.Range("A1").Value & "" & tekst2.Range("A1").Value
    teiseLopp = stringidKoos
End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

No need to add an empty string in the middle, and you need to define your data type. Try

```
Function teiseLopp(tekst1 As String, tekst2 As String) As String
    Dim stringidKoos As String
    stringidKoos = tekst1  & tekst2
    teiseLopp = stringidKoos
End Function
```

Also, why not use a regular formula, as in `=A1&B1`

Comment: This still gives me a value error. But I have planned to use the combined string in function for other purposes.

Comment: The most likely cause is that one your values resolves to the #VALUE! error

Comment: The values are in cells "word" "this" without the "". And teiseLopp is as String and stringidKoos is as String.